# Gound wire connection

Tags: electrical, grounding

I have a 1979 light switch that I am replacing it with sensor switches but I am stumped. The ground wire is attached to a screw at back of the metal box. Do I unscrew it and twist the green ground wire connected to the new switch to the ground wire currently with the screw or do I ground the green wire to another screw on the box?

[image]

Comment: Depends upon local codes.  In some areas residential electrical requires EMT which provides grounding via the metal box. So some more pics would help.

Answer (score 2):

### ANYTIME you have a metal box, cables ground to it *first*

That's a Code requirement.  The ground on entering cables must attach to the metal box.  Now if there's only one ground screw (often: there are holes tapped for a #10-32 screw that don't have a screw installed) you pigtail from that to the cables.

ALL ground wires MUST go together (and to the box) or bad stuff happens.

Definitely do not remove the ground wires from the metal box and do not attach them to the lead off the switch.   In fact, there's a much better way to do that.

### Switches with a metal yoke *automatically* pick up ground

You normally mount switches to the box with steel mounting screws. *For switches*, if their yoke (mounting frame) is metal, or if they have metal wipers touching the mounting screws, they will pick up ground via the metal.

And that's it. No additional grounding necessary. The ground wire there can be left coiled up and capped.

By the way, it's a little trickier for receptacles since they may need to pass many amps of ground current.  They can do the same trick if the yoke has hard clean-metal contact with the metal box, or if they have a special wiper to contact the mounting screw (the latter feature is called "self-grounding" and they will be marked that. The better $4+ receptacles have this.)